# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to render the file `index.html`, but I keep getting

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

when I try to render it. Why can't Flask find my template

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and my file location is like (i chance Tamplates to tamplates)

[image: File location]

Comment: in your error image it is `Tamplates`, while in your code it is `templates`. here is the guide of how the folder structure for flask app looks like https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/layout/

Comment: error still same

Comment: The error in your title doesn't match the error in your question. Also, for what it's worth, `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` is deprecated and should be `from flask_sqlalchemy import ...`

Comment: keep `Tamplates` name in lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you must define the template folder path like this.

if you named your template folder: `Tamplates`

Then use this

`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Tamplates')`